# Elaphant.io json_encode prroblems

Tags: php, socket.io-java-client

When I try to generate json with emit, it puts ' ' at the beginning of the text.

[image]

how can i overcome this problem

Comment: What problem? It's perfectly legal JSON...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be sorted sequentially without quotes